# jQuery - How check if any link was clicked in a specific DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML code my page contains:

```
<div id="main_menu">
  <a href="#" id="login">Link1</a>
  <a href="#" id="logout">Link2</a>
</div>
<div id="second_menu">
  <a href="#" id="information">Link info</a>
  <a href="#" id="profile">My profile</a>
</div>
<div id="menu_oustide"><a href="#" id="something">Link1</a></div>
```

In jQuery if I want to check if the user clicked any link in page I use this code:

```
$('a').click(function() { 

  // do something

});
```

How can I start a function if the user clicked only on links in specific div? I would like to have a function that starts if a user clicked any link only in div ID named "main_menu" AND "second_menu", but not in "menu_outside".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you can bind the event handler to those links only, using the [*descendant* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and [*multiple* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) selectors:

```
$('#main_menu a, #second_menu a').click(function() {
    // link inside #main_menu or #second_menu
});
```

If you don't want to perform the same action for both, you have to bind the event handler individually.

You *could* also check dynamically whether the link is a descendant of any of these element, with [`closest` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if($(this).closest("#main_menu").length) {
        // inside #main_menu
    }
    if($(this).closest("#second_menu").length) {
        // inside #second_menu
    }
    //...
});
```

But that introduces an additional overhead.

Comment: Similarly, if there's a chance you'll be adding more menus in the future, it might be better to use a class rather than list the div ids

Answer (score 1):

use this to select the div and ahref you want.

```
 $('#second_menu a').click(function(){
    // This will select the a href's only in the second menu.
    // basically, in div id "#second_menu" select all "a" elements.
 });
```