# Detect specific link clicked with href and onclick="setLocation()"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect if a link was clicked with `JS`. 
This is my code:

```
<div onclick="setLocation('http://domain.com/test')" class="gd-details" id="detail-box2">
    <h2 class="gd-product-name">
        <a title="test" href="http://domain.com/test">content 1</a>
    </h2>    
</div>
```

I'm also trying with this code and it doesn't works:

```html
 $(document).on("click", "a", function() {
 var href = $(this).attr("href");
  if(href == 'http://domain.com/test'){
   alert('clicked');
  } else { 
   alert('not clicked');
  }
 });
```

How do I detect if a specific link is clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - How check if any link was clicked in a specific DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173604/jquery-how-check-if-any-link-was-clicked-in-a-specific-div)

Comment: You are not really checking if the link is clicked but checking the link clicked is linked to  'http://domain.com/test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event handler to the div click and compare the `onclick` attribute to your test url.

```
  $(document).on("click", "div", function() {
      var href = $(this).attr("onclick");
      if(href === "setLocation('http://domain.com/test')"){ 
        alert('clicked'); 
      } else {
        alert('not clicked'); 
      } 
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, im using "==" not single "="

Comment: hmm, in that case it seems like it should be working, I made this fiddle when testing https://jsfiddle.net/0snrvpmt/

Comment: Yes, it worked with  
`code`
<a title="test" href="http://domain.com/test">content 1</a> 

but it didnt work with 
`code` 
<div onclick="setLocation('http://domain.com/test')" class="gd-details" id="detail-box2">

Comment: The code above will only execute when an anchor `<a>` tag is clicked, it wouldn't work on div clicks

Comment: Yes, so as i said i want to it works with div click also. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, since your edit my answer isn't applicable so i'll delete it soon.

Comment: I have figured out it, it worked with this code: `$(document).on("click", "div", function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("onclick");
  if(href === "setLocation('http://domain.com/test')"){
   alert('clicked');
  } else { 
   alert('not clicked');
  }
 });` . Anyway, thank you so much ! Voted + Marked.